# JQuery Mobile Grouped Button Width - Span 100% of DIV with window.resize

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble forcing these buttons to dynamically resize with the page to fill 100% of the DIV (33% each).

This gets me close, but its not perfect, and it is worse the wider the page is. I've tried setting the width to 33%, but that makes it really narrow.

Is there a better way to do this?

JQuery `$(window).resize` event code:

```
var myWidth = $(window).width() - 1.3*($(window).width() - $('#eventForm').width());
$('.eStatusLabel').css("width", myWidth/3);
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="ui-block-b" id="statusDiv" >
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal" >
        <input type="radio" name="rdStatus" id="eventStatus1" value="yes" />
        <label class="eStatusLabel" for="eventStatus1" >Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdStatus" id="eventStatus2" value="maybe" />
        <label class="eStatusLabel" for="eventStatus2" >Tentative</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdStatus" id="eventStatus3" value="no" />
        <label class="eStatusLabel" for="eventStatus3" >No</label>
     </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.eStatusLabel').css("width",(($('#statusDiv').width()/3)-1));
```

you should use this

Comment: Still does the same thing. I noticed the padding on the side of the page was static, regardless of the window.size, so now I'm using the form width to split into 3. It works great when its narrow (simulating mobile), but the third button overflows to the next line if the browser is around 500px or wider.

Comment: Updated above... The most accurate I've been able to get is taking the entire window width and subtracting the difference between the form and window widths, multiplying by a factor of 1.3

Comment: @jamis0n have you got the solution ? i don't know the exact solution .but you can do like this.

Comment: The best I've been able to get it is with the code mentioned above, using an arbitrary scaling factor that I guess/checked... I don't think using the "width" argument instead of an Array made any difference.

Comment: Now I'm also dealing with exactly when to run this code after the elements are initialized but before the user can see the width change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736184/jquery-mobile-resize-form-elements-before-displaying-page