# JQuery Mobile - Resize Form Elements Before Displaying Page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm resizing a JQM control button group to fit the width of the DIV its contained inside.

However, I want to do this before the user sees anything. Currently, I can only make this work after the page has displayed, which works like a glitch.

Here is my resize code:

```
var myWidth = $(window).width() - 1.3*($(window).width() - $('#eventForm').width());
$('.eStatusLabel').css("width", myWidth/3);
```

Here are the functions I have tried to use to triger this, but the #eventForm width is always 0:

```
$("#myPage").live('pageinit',function(){ //Resize});
$("#myPage").live('pageload',function(){ //Resize});
$("#myPage").live('pagebeforeshow',function(){ //Resize});
```

Is there a way to grab the size of the form before displaying? Is there another way to get the inner width of the content page without the data-role="page" padding included?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for mobile site or responsive site?

Comment: Try to hide element before you apply width and show after the width has been applied.

Answer (score 0):

The only way possible to do this is by overriding the default jquery-mobile css. You can assign and id to the parent element after your page loads and define the width and other properties preceded by the id you are getting after the page loads. The concept is just like loading an html content through ajax and the css gets applied to that html.